# RestSharp: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl, restsharp, windows-8.1

I'm trying to use RestSharp in Visual Studio 2012 Express on a fresh install of Windows 8.1. The API I'm trying to use supports only RC4-SHA for SSL. The certificate is valid.

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = "https://teststore.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/";
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "key");

var request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "time.json";

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(bcrequest);
```

I keep getting an error from the client: `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`. I thought there were certificate problems, until I finally took a packet capture and discovered there were no cipher suites in common. RC4-SHA is not available on the client end. After installing Windows 7 and running the exact same code, the problem goes away.

#### Why is RC4-SHA unavailable in RestSharp on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had an application the failed tls handshake after I insalled Win 8.1. My Wireshark captures on working and non working client logons showed missing cipher suites. Installing a real certificate on the server I was connecting to also solved the problem. The server had a self signed certificate.

I finally found [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303404.aspx):

> RC4 is no longer enabled by default for TLS. Applications (such as
>   Internet Explorer) might fail to connect if they depend on RC4
>
> You can enable RC4 support by configuring these registry keys with the
>   following REG command:
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers]`
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4
>   128/128]"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff`
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4
>   40/128]"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff`
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4
>   56/128]"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff`

Comment: There is a solution for disable handshake programmatically (on dev version only, be careful !) on this site : http://robertgreiner.com/2013/03/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel/
Just add line `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;` before any network call

Answer (score 11):

I always add the following line of code before making the initial network connection to solve this issue.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

Comment: Setting the .Net SecurityProtocolType to the .Net TLS version 1.2 resolved it for me. Seems like Restsharp is selecting the incorrect one by default.